# Error while setting Sql Express 2012 as prerequisite

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have developed a `WPF` app which is using `.Net (Framework 4.5)` and `SQL server 2012`.  It works perfectly fine, but I am having a problem when I try to publish this app using the one click approach.

I placed `dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe` in the `DotNetFX45` folder and `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe`,`SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe` in `SqlExpress 2012`.

Now when I set prerequiste as `.NET Framework 4.5` and `SQL Express 2012` it gives me following error:

> "Error 4   To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE' for item 'SQL Server 2012 Express' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883."
>
> "Error 5   To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE' for item 'SQL Server 2012 Express' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883."

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @CristiC777 No if you can solve it let me know :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Also, I noticed you have a space in the folder you said you placed it into and the message has no space - could this be it? ('SqlExpress2012')

Comment: Putting the SQL installer files in the "en" subfolder, i.e. SqlExpress2012/en/SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE (contrary to the error message which says SqlExpress2012/SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

1. Locate the folder 
   (for 32 bit OS) `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2012\en`. (For 64 bit OS) `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2012\en`
2. Open file `package.xml`
3. Locate `<String Name="SqlExpr32Exe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=230852&amp;clcid=0x409</String>`. The link may vary in your copy. Copy the link and paste it in your web browser. A save file dialogue box will appear. Click on Save. After downloading the file, paste it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2012\en\`
4. Locate `<String Name="SqlExpr64Exe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=230853&amp;clcid=0x409</String>` and follow the same process as described in point 3.

Try to re-build the setup project again.

Answer (score 0):

I relocated `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` and `SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe` to this location and fixed for me :
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2012\en`